# Javascript autorefresh HTML if button pressed

Tags: javascript, html, refresh

I have the following item:

```
<a class="btn btn-danger w-100" style='color: White' id='refresh_button' onclick="activateAutorefresh()"> ↺ </a>
```

I want the following: If the class is `btn-danger`, `onClick` change it to `btn-success` and activate autorefresh with a timeout of 5000 milliseconds. If button is clicked once more, change class to `btn-danger` and disable autorefresh.

So, I have the following code:

```
function activateAutorefresh(){
    if (document.getElementById("refresh_button").classList.contains('btn-danger')){
        document.getElementById("refresh_button").classList.remove('btn-danger');
        document.getElementById("refresh_button").classList.add('btn-success');
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("refresh_button").classList.remove('btn-success');
        document.getElementById("refresh_button").classList.add('btn-danger');
    }
}
```

I don't know how to activate/disable the page autorefresh. How can I do this?

Also, on refresh mantain the current autorefresh state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOM **[`element.classList` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)** is the key to this as you have been using, but you also need to use a **[timer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)** to asynchronously count and refresh the page.

Now, when the page is refreshed all data about the prior page will be lost, so you have to store the data you'll need and then pull it back out. This can be done in a variety of ways, but **[`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** is the simplest.

NOTE: The code won't work here in the Stack Overflow "Code Snippet" environment due to security reasons, but it will work when running on a web server.

```js
// Place all of the following code in a <script> that is just before the closing body tag (</body>) 

// Get reference to element
var link = document.getElementById("refresh_button");

// Retrieve the last state of the link's classes from localStorage
link.className = localStorage.getItem("linkClassList");

// Set up the event handler
link.addEventListener("click", activateAutoRefresh);

let timer = null; // Will hold reference to timer

function activateAutoRefresh(evt){

  // Test to see if the clicked element has the "btn-danger" class
  if(this.classList.contains("btn-danger")){
    this.classList.remove("btn-danger");
    this.classList.add("btn-success");
    timer = setTimeout(function(){ location = location;}, 5000); // Refresh after 5 seconds
  } else {
    this.classList.remove("btn-success");
    this.classList.add("btn-danger"); 
    clearTimeout(timer);  // Cancel the timer
  }
}

// Set the link's class list into localStorage
link.className = localStorage.setItem("linkClassList", link.className);
```

```html
<a class="btn btn-danger w-100" id='refresh_button' href="#"> ↺ </a>
```

Comment: you forgot to save the `setTimeout(...)` reference into `time`

Comment: This is almost perfect! After refreshing, the button becomes to `btn-danger`, how I can make it to remember the `btn-success`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus It isn't working Scott. After refresh, button goes back to `btn-danger`

Comment: @ScottMarcus This is the error: null is not an object (evaluating 'link.className')

Comment: @Lechucico Make sure that all this code is inside of a `script` element and that element is placed just before the closing `body` tag (`</body>`).

Answer (score 0):

You should write different functions to handle auto refresh and enable/disable the timer,

```
var arTimer;
function enableTimer() {
    arTimer = setTimeout(autoRefresh, 5000);
}

function disableTimer() {
    clearTimeout(arTimer);
}

function autoRefresh() {
    /* Code for auto refresh goes here */
}
```

call `enableTimer()` when you want to start the timer and call `diableTimer()` when you want to clear the timer before it expires.

`autoRefresh()` function should contain the code for auto refresh.